# List.OrderBy returns a collection of empty strings

Tags: linq, sql-order-by

I have a collection string date values some of which are empty strings ("").

when I use OrderBy clause, following statement

theList = theList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.age).ToList()

returns empty string collection.

However, if I use OrderByDescending operator, the result is correctly ordered by descending data values.

Sample date values are "2014-10-31 00:00:00.000", "2014-09-30 00:00:00.000", "2014-11-30 00:00:00.000", "", "2014-08-31 00:00:00.000".

What could be the problem please?

Thank you,

Piyush Varma

Comment: Please provide real code. The example you provided is not enough to see whats wrong here.

Comment: Here is the code:        Dim returnCollection As List(Of FundedAccountsDetail) = New List(Of FundedAccountsDetail)
Select Case sortBy
 Case "billedthru"
   If Ascending = "ASC" Then
     returnCollection = reportCollection.OrderBy(Function(x) x.BilledThru.Substring(0, 10)).ToList()
   ElseIf Ascending = "DESC" Then
     returnCollection = reportCollection.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.BilledThru).ToList()
   End If
Case Else
   returnCollection = reportCollection
End Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct would be that if x.billedthru is ever shorter than 10 characters, you could see this behavior. Does it return rows if you try this:

```
Dim returnCollection As List(Of FundedAccountsDetail) = New List(Of FundedAccountsDetail) 
Select Case sortBy 
Case "billedthru"
   If Ascending = "ASC" Then
      returnCollection = reportCollection.OrderBy(Function(x) x.BilledThru).ToList()
   ElseIf Ascending = "DESC" Then
      returnCollection = reportCollection.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.BilledThru).ToList() 
   End If
Case Else
      returnCollection = reportCollection
End Select
```

If it does, then the problem is the substring. If not, I admit that it is perplexing. What I'd probably try is then removing the order by from the first branch of the if and see if it returns rows. Basically work my way back until that branch of the if works and then rebuild it step by step until I start having the problem.

Comment: I removed the Substring and tried your suggestion. OrderBy still returns all empty strings. OrderByDescending works well!

Comment: I replaced NULL values with "" and OrderBy() s working! Thanks a lot.